# Load interfaces dynamically from typescript definition d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, import

I have a `.d.ts` file which contains interfaces. I do not know what interfaces exist in advance. The `.d.ts` files are generated by a third part library and **not** from corresponding `.ts` files.

```
export interface ExampleInterface1 {
  id: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface ExampleInterface2 {
  id: string;
  type: string;
}
```

As such, I want to load the `.d.ts dynamically

```
const data = await import('path/to/my/dynamically/created/file'); // without .d.ts extension
```

However, this does not work with `.d.ts` files. I tested with other files, including JSON, and the contents are loaded fine into the `data` variable.

I can import manually, but of course, this does not help my situation.

```
import { ExampleInterface1, ExampleInterface2 } from 'path/to/my/dynamically/created/file';
```

How can I load the interface names and contents dynamically from a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Interfaces do not exist on run time so import them manually will not work.

Comment: I was programmatically parsing them to create single index 'barrel' files as part of a package library. In the end, rather than creating a parser to find and ignore duplicate imports, I found that the underlying library I was using did mostly same thing. Finally I just read the contents of different `d.ts` files and dumb merged them which was good enough for my use case.